# Много таблиц в БД, плохо ли это?

Tags: mysql, php, innodb, sql

планирую в будущем иметь около **30-450 таблиц** ( создаются постепенно, в зависимости от количества информации). Так вот, будет ли слишком пагубно в конце иметь **400 таблиц** (макс), **по 5-20 записей**. мне нужно именно так, или может будет очень пагубно?

P.S всего **1 БД**, таблицы с текстом. Просто так таблиц много, это помогает реализовать создание категорий в категориях.

Comment: категории в категориях... а чем не устроил вариант с доп полем parent в котором будет писаться ИД родителя?

Comment: А чем не подошел вариант, который был описан [тут](http://hashcode.ru/questions/306727/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-php-mysqli)?

Comment: Это тоже вариант, но мне нужно знать слишком ли плохо много таблиц ? просто переделывать очень долго

Comment: Просто иметь 5 000 товаров и 100 категорий в 1й таблице не очень удобно

Comment: @Юра Сучко, не, подождите) товары в одной таблице, категории в другой, привязка товаров к категориям в третьей... это как минимум. а плоддить для КАЖДОЙ категории таблицу будет в конце концов накладно, а еше надо будет как то следить за названиями таблиц... не ройте себе яму :) смотрите на мир проще....

Comment: если вы хотите услышать boolean ответ, то: да, как минимум для вашей задачи это будет очень плохо. @Fike правильный линк привел с ответом на ваш вопрос.

Comment: Нет, связь не 3-й таблицей, а в таблице с категориями есть поле что бы связать определенную категория с другими категориями или таблицей с товарами

Comment: Почему? Кто так решил? А товар не может входить в несколько категорий?

Comment: Юрий, а если понадобиться поиск по всем товарам, вы будете делать 30-450 запросов?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если оставить в стороне вопросы моделирования, то иметь много таблиц хорошо при модификации (меньше блокировок и перестроек индексов), но плохо при выборке (если приходится их соединять в запросах).
Так что окончательный ответ зависит от того, как будет использоваться ваша база.